# Have an error with accept function and write and read methods in C++ using XCode

Tags: c++

I'm programing TCP/IP sockets and when I pass the arguments to the accept function, there's an error saying "No matching function for call to 'accept'".

newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr * ) &cli_addr, &clilen);

Comment: What type is `clilen`?

Comment: I have the same issue. This is the 3rd step to set up a TCP(?) server, where ``sockfd`` is the currently used socket, cli_addr is an ``int`` that will hold the connected client's address and clilen is another ``int`` holding the address length.

Answer (score 0):

defining the correct datatypes for the `accept()` function did the trick:

```
int newsockfd;
struct sockaddr cli_addr;
socklen_t clilen;

newsockfd = accept(socketfd, &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

Now it works in Xcode...

**NB**: When you start typing `accept(` and autocomplete, you will see:

```
accept(<int>, <struct sockaddr *>, <socklen_t *>)
```

I just made sure all variables I pass were the same type. Sort of handy if this happens again.

**NB2**: If you want to learn socket programming I can highly recommend this [tutorial](http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/). There is a little error in the server side on the `accept()` function (hence me stumbling over this question), but the downloadable C++ files work are correct and work fine.

Comment: So long-story-short: Use the correct types.  Wow, what a revelation.